# Is css scroll snap impossible with Astra theme?

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll

Once again, I'm beat. I'm working on https://adastraretouch.com and using the WP Astra theme. I've tried everything but can't get scroll snap to work. I took the css out now because at this point I don't even know where to put it because I've tried every container and section. I just wanted a simply scroll snap on each section. If you have spare time, let me know. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it is best to reach out to their theme's developer for support since this is a paid theme

Comment: i'm using the free version but yeah, i'll contact them too in case they know something. i don't really know if it specifically has to do with the theme but i'll give it a go